# How to search for a text and copy/paste to next line

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script to look for a `SOME_WORD`. If I find one, I want to copy whole line and paste to next line and replace `SOME_WORD` with `NEW_WORLD`.

Thank you for the help!!

current shell script

```
search_value="SOME_WORD"
file_path="./abc.ts"

# line=$(grep "$search_value" "$file_path")

if [ -z "$file_path" ]; then
  echo "Value not found"
  exit 1
fi

# Search file for variable and copy next line
while read -r line
do
  if [[ "$line" == *"$search_value"* ]]; then
    read -r next_line
    sed -i "/$line/{p; s/.*/$next_line\\
&/}" "$file_path"
  fi
done < "$file_path"
```

BEFORE

```
SOME_WORD_1: 'ABC',
BAD_WORD_1: 'ABC',
SOME_WORD_2: 'ABC',
BAD_WORD_1: 'ABC',
SOME_WORD_3: 'ABC'
```

AFTER

```
SOME_WORD_1: 'ABC',
NEW_WORLD_1: 'ABC',
BAD_WORD_1: 'ABC',
SOME_WORD_2: 'ABC',
NEW_WORLD_2: 'ABC',
BAD_WORD_1: 'ABC',
SOME_WORD_3: 'ABC',
NEW_WORLD_3: 'ABC',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ed` is available/acceptable, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s file.txt <<-'EOF'
  g/SOME_WORD/t.\
  s//NEW_WORLD/
  g/[^,]$/s/$/,/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

In one-line:

```
printf '%b\n' 'g/SOME_WORD/t.\\\ns//NEW_WORLD/' 'g/[^,]$/s/$/,/' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

---

With shell variables, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

search_value="SOME_WORD"
replace_value="NEW_WORLD"
file_path="./abc.ts"

ed -s "$file_path" <<-EOF
  g|$search_value|t.\\
  s||$replace_value|g
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

- The `ed` script is using a [HEREDOC](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) (EOF and EOF)
- `−s`  Suppress the writing of byte counts by e, E, r, and w commands and of the '!'  prompt after a !command.
- `g|$search_value|t.`

  - `g` means global the pattern search starts from first to the last line/buffer.
  - `$search_value` is a shell variable.
  - `t` means copy, in this case copy the pattern inside the `| |`
  - `.` means copy to the same line buffer, the effect is a duplicate line.
  - `\\` The second `\` is just a continuation of the pattern search, the first `\` is to escape the second `\` from the shell, since it i special to the shell.
  - `g/./t.` To show an example of duplicating each line.
- `s||$replace_value|g`

  - `s` same as in `sed`
  - `||` Double means process whatever is (the previous) match from `|$search_value|`
  - `g` The trailing `g` means to search from the whole line.

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in_place* editing is needed.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.
- See GNU [ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04)
- See POSIX [ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm actually looking to add to same file.. not in file.txt.. how can i do that?

Comment: Oh okay so its not a path, its file name? FYI, file is in different directory

Comment: Updated to use shell variables.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: solution seems working but it doesn't write actual file

Comment: No error message. I just verified in terminal print looks good but actual file doesn't have change

Comment: Please have a look at  the comment below at my post.

Comment: oh i see.. got it.. I just replaced with w it worked but added unnecessary `,` how can i remove that?

Comment: Remove the `g/[^,]$/s/$/,/`

Comment: oh sweet.. One last thing, how can I replace all matching string? right now its replacing first matching only

Comment: // import * as SOME_WORD from './some/SOME_WORD/something'; to // import * as NEW_WORLD from './some/NEW_WORLD/something';

Comment: The `g` means global so the script should work as expected and should match all

Comment: interesting.. it only changes first matching within same line

Comment: Add an additional `g` at the end and change the delimiter from `/` to `|`

Comment: im not 100% follow what that means.. would you be able to show me in code?

Comment: Thank you so much! If you don't mind what this script actually do? I'm not a expert at bash. syntax as well!

Answer (score 0):

Let us first assume your strings do not contain regex operators (`.`, `*`...).

With `sed`:

```
from="SOME_WORD"
to="NEW_WORLD"
sed -ni "p;s/$from/$to/gp" "$file_path"
```

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -i inplace -v from="SOME_WORD" -v to="NEW_WORLD" '
  {print} $0 ~ from {gsub(from, to); print}' "$file_path"
```

If your strings can contain regex operators GNU `awk` should be preferred:

```
awk -i inplace -v from="SOM*_WO.D" -v to="NEW_WORLD" '
  {print}
  { p = 0
    while(i = index($0, from)) {
      $0 = substr($0, 1, i - 1) to substr($0, i + length(from))
      p = 1
    }
  } p' "$file_path"
```